# How to set div block 'vertical-align:bottom' on the image

Tags: html, css

How to set div block vertical-align:bottom?
(The div block should be over the image.)

```
.block{
    background-color:#999999;
    width:480px;height:100px;

    position:absolute;

    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    }


<div style="display: table; height: 480px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="block">This is the text.</div>
    <img src="image.jpg" width="480" height="480"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the problem that you want the text to be aligned to the bottom of the box? It appears your solution works for putting the div over the image, here's an example: [http://jsfiddle.net/lsirivong/8wjzs/](http://jsfiddle.net/lsirivong/8wjzs/). I moved your inline style out into the css, made the box transparent to emphasize the overlay, and commented out some styles that don't seem necessary as Umesh points out below.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that I also had applied Purmou's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Change `vertical-align:bottom` to `bottom:0`.

This way, the `div` will stick to the bottom of the container (and it works out since the container has `position:relative`).

Comment: When I set it to bottom:0, the div go to the bottom of the brower.I need div bottom of the image.

Comment: It's because the container doesn't have a set height. Do you need it to be fluid height?

Answer (score 0):

All your code works, but all style properties are not required. I tested just below working code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.block{
    background-color:#999999;
    width:480px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    height: 480px;  
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block">This is the text.</div>
    <img src="image.jpg" width="480" height="480"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Can try disabling the unrequried style with firebug? It will reduce the lines of code.